# The project was not built due to "Could not delete 'project/bin/classes/com',"

Tags: android, eclipse

I've seen this error before and I've solved it before by just cleaning a project but this time it just doesn't work. This error sometimes appears when I import a certain project from existing code.

Things I've tried so far:

- Clean the project (this fixes it just for long enough so I can compile it but then the error reappears, it gets annoying to clean the project every time when I want to compile it)
- Deleted bin folder manually and then cleaned the project (same effect as "clean" option, it fixed the problem for a minute)

I've done a lot of research on this and everyone says that cleaning the project should fix it but it doesn't.

EDIT: Some additional details:

- I'm using the latest version of eclipse
- My workspace is in a Dropbox synced folder because I'm sharing it between two computers (maybe the problem lies there?)
- When I click on the console tab, there's one more error saying "unable to write jarlist cache file C:/users/user/dropbox/android development/workspace/project/bin/jarlist.cache"

Comment: Check the permissions for the bin directory of the project. If necessary, add write permission. And have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660961/eclipse-could-not-delete-error

Comment: @Mark029348 I already checked this question but I didn't find anything useful. Could you tell me how to check permissions for bin directory? thank you!

Comment: Just open windows explorer, right click, properties, ... and check if you have full permissions for the directory. This is not always the case, as the project your download, might have permissions attached from the previous user.

Comment: @Mark029348 I have full permissions oer the folder. The "read only" box was ticked and i unticked it but then when I cleaned the project it ticked itself back.

Comment: @Matthew You have to provide more details such as what IDE you are using and what versions of IDE and Plugins you are using. Basically more info about your build environment would help. The answer to your problem depends on so many factors. Narrow it down for us. Thx.

Comment: @harikris I provided all the additional info that I can think of. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found where the problem was. It's because I have the workspace in a dropbox folder. That's a shame because I really want to sync workspace between computers. The error goes away when I "pause" dropbox sysncing and comes back when I run it again.

Answer (score 0):

This can actually also be a rights issue. I'm also running my Android project in my Dropbox folder - quite useful -, but stopping Dropbox didn't solved it.

If you're on Linux, you can `cd` in the right folder an run:

```
sudo chown your_user:your_group -R ./
sudo chmod u+w -R ./
```

On windows, just check (right click on the project folder -> Properties) that your user and group have the read/write rights in the project folder **and its subfolders**.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Some additional information on the subject:

As the OP I have also had the same problem, class-files was not build because bin subfolders was not deleted. I have my workspace on a network attached drive (at work) with a "offline" feature, files are stored localy and synced when I'm online or plugged in at my work. Because of syncproblems Eclipse are not able to delete bin-subfolders and as a result no class files are produced. Clean doesn't fix it but the error messages in "Problems" points in the right direction.

My solution was to eliminate all files, and folders that had "syncproblems" (within the sync-center for my windows "offline files").
I'm on a windows 10 machine and the offline feature is (I think) a microsoft network solution.
My first post so I'm sorry if it's inadequate in any way. Hopefully someone is helped by this